# Events before $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a functionality to hide controls conditionally before the document is loaded. If I put this functionality on `$(document).ready`, I see the page flickering to hide the controls conditionally. I would like to know if there is an event that can be called before `$(document).ready` is triggered.

Comment: Can't you set them to hidden by default and only show the ones you need on `$(document).ready`?

Comment: When you say hidden by default, are you reffering to use css to have them hidden. If I do this, will jquery be able to show and hide them?

Comment: Yes, I do mean by CSS, and yes, jQuery can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others mentioned do something like this

```
<div id="test" class="hidden"> my hidden div tag </div>

.hidden
{
 display:none;   
}
```

in the document.ready , you can show , this is equivalent of onload , which waits till html is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').show();
});
```

jsfiddle example here

http://jsfiddle.net/kdpAr/

Answer (score 6):

Common issue.  Use CSS to have the controls hidden by default and then use JS upon `$(document).ready` to decide which controls to make visible.  There will be no flicker.  It will just look like the appropriate parts of the page are loading progressively.

You can't safely run JS before the document is ready and parts of the document will be visible before you can run JS.  So, the only solution is to make sure all non-flicker elements are hidden by default and you then only show the ones you want visible.

The simplest way to do this is to just put a common class on all dynamic elements:

```
<div id="myControl1" class="initiallyHidden"></div>
```

and use CSS to make sure they all start out hidden:

```
.initiallyHidden {display: none;}
```

And then your javascript will override that when it decides an element should be visible:

```
document.getElementById("myControl1").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 1):

When I've needed to hide something before Javascript is loaded I would set it hidden in css like so:

```
 display:none;
```

or:

```
 visibility: hidden;
```

You can also use conditions in combination with Javascript to reveal it if need be.

Comment: or since jquery was mentioned: `class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"`

Answer (score 1):

call the JavaScript function in next to HTML element

**ex:**

```
<span></span>
<script> call JS function</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, in this way will not be able to do things generically. If I have to hide and show multiple Elements then doing so with what you have show might not be the right choice

Comment: agreed but you can refer all the external JavaScript reference end of the page. and cal the JavaScript function after all element. this will save the referenced file load time.then you can run the function before all file loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open a script tag right after the HTML you want to hide condionnaly (jQuery must be declared before however) and then call hide directly, not inside a $(document).ready like this :

```
<div id="toHide">Lorem ipsum</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#toHide").hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your elements BEFORE running your javascript

```
<div>hi</div>
<script>
$("div").css('background-color', '#EEE');
</script>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d01a1